# Numpy matrix operations on custom C structures with overloaded operators

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes, cython

I'm working on a project which requires handling matrices of custom C structures, with some C functions implementing operations over these structures.

So far, we're proceeding as follows:

- Build python wrapper classes around the C structures using ctypes
- Override `__and__` and `__xor__` for that object calling the appropriate underlying C functions
- Build `numpy` arrays containing instances of these classes

Now we are facing some performance issues, and I feel this is not a proper way to handle this thing because we have a C library implementing natively expensive operations on the data type, then numpy implementing natively expensive operations on matrixes, but (I guess) in this configuration every single operation will be proxyed by the python wrapper class.

Is there a way to implement this with numpy that make the operations fully native? I've read there are utilities for wrapping ctypes types into numpy arrays ([see](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html) [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html)), but what about the operator overloading?

We're not bound to using ctypes, but we would love to be able to still use python (which I believe has big advantages over C in terms of code maintainability...)

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how? Would you suggest other different solutions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah, I would suggest another solution. numpy isn't really engineered to be efficient under such use. it really depends on what you want to do exactly, so perhaps you could elaborate on that a little; but as a generality, a 'struct of arrays' approach is more numpy friendly than an 'array of structs' approach. note that you can use both approaches interchangeably, by offsetting your structs / striding your arrays appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate somewhat on the above comment (arrays of structs versus struct of arrays):

```
import numpy as np
#create an array of structs
array_of_structs = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=[('a', np.float64), ('b',np.int32)])
#we may as well think of it as a struct of arrays
struct_of_arrays = array_of_structs['a'], array_of_structs['b']
#this should print 8
print array_of_structs['b'].ctypes.data - array_of_structs['a'].ctypes.data
```

Note that working with a 'struct of arrays' approach requires a rather different coding style. That is, we largely have to let go of the OOP way of organizing our code. Naturally, you may still choose to place all operations relating to a particular object in a single namespace, but such a data layout encourages a more vectorized, or numpythonic coding style. Rather than passing single objects around between functions, we rather take the whole collection or matrix of objects to be the smallest atomic construct that we manipulate.

Of course, the same data may also be accessed in an OOP manner, where it is desirable. But that will not do you much good as far as numpy is concerned. Note that for performance reasons, it is often also preferable to maintain each attribute of your object as a separate contiguous array, since placing all attributes contiguously is cache-inefficient for operations which act on only a subset of attributes of the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about this way of indexing numpy arrays. However, I'm afraid this approach is not applicable to my case, because the C `struct`s contain non-standard data types (large integers from the GMP library), and the operations among them are implemented as C functions (and to me they are black boxes).

Comment: I am still lacking the background to really appreciate your problem, but I get the impression you had best stick to C for this subproblem. there isn't a single numpy/scipy function that is going to take kindly to your large integer math. nonetheless, if you encapsulated some subset of functionality in C, you could build the rest of your functionality in python. for instance, you could view specific attributes of a C++ vector of your structs as an array in python.